# how to install SQL server 2012 from your application installer

Tags: sql-server-2012, installation, windows-installer, installshield

My application (WPF 4.0) needs SQL Server 2012 and I need to package it with my installer (installshield). Is there a correct way to do it?

Comment: There may be a checkbox under the Project Assistant tab, Installation Requirements section.  If not you may need to add it as a prerequisite.  This link may be of help:  http://www.installationdeveloper.com/3356/how-to-install-sql-server-2008-express-r2-in-installshield/

Comment: You can't just get the full SQL Server and install it with your product. It's a licensed priced product that the user has to obtain. If you have a special agreement with MS you may be able to ship the SQL CD together with yours, but you can't just install it outside the pricing licensing rules.

Comment: This is late in the development process, but Sql Server is really meant for a shared database, on dedicated hardware. It kinda sucks as the datastore for a single-user local application. You would have been better off with Compact Edition, Sqlite, or even Access as your DB.

Comment: Is there any light weight/redistibutable version SQL Server 2012 Express? may like the SQL Compact type?